# Sql limit record grouped

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, limit

I have a table 'Players' 
In this table the columns are `'ID','surname','nation'`
I need a query and result must shows a list of Players by nations limited by 4 for nations
Ex
Table players

```
ID   surn.. nation
1    Garcia   spa
2    smith    gbr
3    rossi    ita
4    villa    spa
5    renoir   fra
6    muller   ger
7    conti    ita
8    johnson  usa
9    james    gbr
10   lopez    spa
11   dubois   fra
12   petit    fra
13   popov    rus
14  rodriguez spa
15   weber    ger
16   ivanov   rus
17  gonzales  spa
18   wagner   ger
19   bruni    ita
20   Smirnov  rus
21   white    gbr
22   schmidt  ger
23  Armstrong usa
24    green   gbr
25   Schulz   ger
```

Resultset

```
Nation| surname-
Spa |Garcia-
Spa| villa-
Spa| lopez-
Spa |rodriguez-
Gbr |smith-
Gbr |james-
Gbr| white-
Gbr| green -
Ita| rossi-
Ita |conti-
Ita |bruni-
Fra |renoir-
Fra| dubois-
Fra| petit-
Ger |muller-
Ger| weber-
Ger| wagner-
Ger |schmidt-
Usa |johnson -
Usa |armstrong-
Rus| popov-
Rus |ivanov-
Rus |Smirnov -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `row_number()` window function:

```
select t.nation, t.surname
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by nation order by id) rn
  from players
) t
where t.rn <= 4
order by t.nation, t.id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bZaS8BFP4qmqWueHjD4GiZ/0).
Or if your version of SQLite does not support window functions:

```
select t.nation, t.surname
from (
  select p.*,
    (select count(*) + 1 from players where nation = p.nation and id < p.id) rn
  from players p
) t
where t.rn <= 4
order by t.nation, t.id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bZaS8BFP4qmqWueHjD4GiZ/2).
Results:

```
| nation | surname   |
| ------ | --------- |
| fra    | renoir    |
| fra    | dubois    |
| fra    | petit     |
| gbr    | smith     |
| gbr    | james     |
| gbr    | white     |
| gbr    | green     |
| ger    | muller    |
| ger    | weber     |
| ger    | wagner    |
| ger    | schmidt   |
| ita    | rossi     |
| ita    | conti     |
| ita    | bruni     |
| rus    | popov     |
| rus    | ivanov    |
| rus    | Smirnov   |
| spa    | Garcia    |
| spa    | villa     |
| spa    | lopez     |
| spa    | rodriguez |
| usa    | johnson   |
| usa    | Armstrong |
```

Comment: Error continues to persist

Comment: What is your version of SQLite?

Comment: Sqlite db browser V2.2

Comment: Run this query: `select sqlite_version();` and you will get the version.

Comment: See my edited answer with another query for SQLite that does not support window functions.

Comment: 3.7.7.1 is the version

Comment: This is a very old version. Use my 2nd query.

Comment: Download the newest version of db browser for SQLite.

Comment: Thank you for your time